# Calculating cost of an order using PHP

Tags: php, forms

So I have zero knowledge of PHP, but i can maneuver my way through problems in html, javascript, and css. My task is to calculate the cost of an order, based on the quantity of an item the user inputs. All I really know how to do is set variables and write a function since they are similar to javascript. So far the form looks like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Light bulb Sales</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="light.php" method="post">
<h2>Welcome to Light of your Life Light bulb Sales</h2>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Buyer's Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Street Address:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="address" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>City, State, Zip:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="location" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p />

<table border="border">
<tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>100-watt Light Bulbs (4)</td>
    <td>$2.39</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="fourLight" size="3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>100-watt Light Bulbs (8)</td>
    <td>$4.29</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="eightLight" size="3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>100-watt long-lie Light Bulbs (4)</td>
    <td>$3.95</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="fourLong" size="3" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>100-watt long-lie Light Bulbs (8)</td>
        <td>$7.49</td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="eightLong" size="3" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Order" />
<input type="reset" value="Clear order Form" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I need the php page to do is to post what the user ordered along with how much it will cost in a table. My mess of a php page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lightbulb sales</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$name=$_POST['name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$location=$_POST['location'];
$total=;
$tax=.08;
$checkout=;
$quantity=;
$price=;
function computeCost(){

}

print $name;<br />
print $address;<br />
print $location;<br />
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not looking for someone to just give me the answer as I wish to learn how to do this, I would appreciate any hints or any examples.

Comment: What did error reporting have to say?

Comment: Nothing shows up when I submit the form. I just get redirected to a blank page

Comment: If you're looking for a JS solution, I am definitely not your man for the job. You can Google it. *But,* I can say this; you would basically need to do what you did for your other POST variables. In a nutshell; `$item_1 = (int)$_POST['item_1']; $item_2 = (int)$_POST['item_2']; $total = $item_1 + $item_2; echo $total;`

Comment: I'm looking for a php solution not javascript. My main issues is pulling the prices of each item from the table, since they don't have a name.

Comment: If I need anymore questions answered, will you be available to respond to extra comments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64911/discussion-between-ryan-sisson-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with for you. I think it's easier to just write this one out.

Using numerous PHP functions such as:

- [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)
- [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)
- [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)
- [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Sidenote: You may want to replace user inputs with drop down selects.

PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lightbulb sales</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$location = $_POST['location'];

/* ====================== ITEMS ====================== */

/* fourLight */
if(isset($_POST['fourLight'])  && !empty($_POST['fourLight']) && is_numeric($_POST['fourLight']) ){

    $fourLight = $_POST['fourLight'];
    $fourLight_price = "2.39";
    $total_fourLight = $fourLight * $fourLight_price;

echo "Four light: $" . number_format($total_fourLight,2);
echo "<br>";

}
else{ $total_fourLight = 0; }


/* eightLight */
if(isset($_POST['eightLight'])  && !empty($_POST['eightLight']) && is_numeric($_POST['eightLight']) ){

    $eightLight = $_POST['eightLight'];
    $eightLight_price = "4.29";
    $total_eightLight = $eightLight * $eightLight_price;

echo "Eight Light: $" . number_format($total_eightLight,2);
echo "<br>";

}

else{ $total_eightLight = 0; }

/* fourLong */
if(isset($_POST['fourLong']) && !empty($_POST['fourLong']) && is_numeric($_POST['fourLong']) ){

    $fourLong = $_POST['fourLong'];
    $fourLong_price = "3.95";
    $total_fourLong = $fourLong * $fourLong_price;

echo "Four Long: $" . number_format($total_fourLong,2);
echo "<br>";

}

else{ $total_fourLong = 0; }


/* eightLong */
if(isset($_POST['eightLong'])  && !empty($_POST['eightLong']) && is_numeric($_POST['eightLong']) ){

    $eightLong = $_POST['eightLong'];
    $eightLong_price = "7.49";
    $total_eightLong = $eightLong * $eightLong_price;

echo "Eight Long: $" . number_format($total_eightLong,2);
echo "<br>";

}

else{ $total_eightLong = 0; }


/* ====================== TALLY ====================== */

$sub_total = $total_fourLight + $total_eightLight + $total_fourLong + $total_eightLong;

$grand_total_items = number_format($sub_total, 2);

echo "<hr>";
echo "Sub-total: $" . $grand_total_items;
echo "<br>";

$tax= 1.08; // tax is calculated this way, not just .08

$grand_total = $grand_total_items * $tax;

echo "Grand total including 8% tax: $" . number_format($grand_total,2);

echo "<br>";

$checkout = "Checkout text here.";

// Not sure what you want to do with this
function computeCost(){

}

/* ====================== PRINT OTHER ====================== */

print "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
print "Address: " . $address . "<br>";
print "Place: " . $location . "<br>";

print "<hr>";
print $checkout . "<br>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here's a dropdown select version of your form, which will ensure numeric values.

Sidenote: I've renamed all of the original inputs with an added `_other` suffix, should you decide to use them later as an "other" option. Those have been commented out `<!-- -->`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Light bulb Sales</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="light.php" method="post">
<h2>Welcome to Light of your Life Light bulb Sales</h2>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Buyer's Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Street Address:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="address" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>City, State, Zip:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="location" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
</table>


<table border="4">
<tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>100-watt Light Bulbs (4)</td>
    <td>$2.39</td>
    <td align="center">

  <select size="1" name="fourLight">
    <option selected>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
  </select>

<!-- commented out input -->
<!--
<input type="text" name="fourLight_other" size="3" />
-->

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>100-watt Light Bulbs (8)</td>
    <td>$4.29</td>
    <td align="center">

  <select size="1" name="eightLight">
    <option selected>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
  </select>

<!-- commented out input -->
<!--
<input type="text" name="eightLight_other" size="3" />
-->

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>100-watt long-lie Light Bulbs (4)</td>
    <td>$3.95</td>
    <td align="center">

  <select size="1" name="fourLong">
    <option selected>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
  </select>

<!-- commented out input -->
<!--
<input type="text" name="fourLong_other" size="3" />
-->

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>100-watt long-lie Light Bulbs (8)</td>
        <td>$7.49</td>
        <td align="center">

  <select size="1" name="eightLong">
    <option selected>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
  </select>

<!-- commented out input -->
<!--
<input type="text" name="eightLong_other" size="3" />
-->

</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit Order" />
<input type="reset" value="Clear order Form" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

If you want to do it dynamically for the quantities for the dropdowns, instead of adding options:

Modify these values `$i = 0; $i <= 24` from 0 to whatever number.

```
<select name="fourLight">
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 24; $i++) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

Copy that code while changing the name attribute accordingly for the others.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had actually just given up last night. I had spent close to 5 hours on this and got no where. So I ended up doing a longer version of what you provided where I just declared the values as I needed them.

Comment: Hi Ryan. @RyanSisson You're very much welcome. I had fun building this actually. These are the types of projects I enjoy doing and was glad to have helped, *cheers*

Comment: @RyanSisson I always like to improve on my answers whenever I feel there could be improvements made. Reload my answer and near the end where it reads as *"If you want to do it dynamically..."* - It will save you a lot of extra coding (time), should you want to use dropdown selects instead of user input.